# Размер кнопок в блоке Яндекс.Поделиться

Tags: javascript, css, ya-share2

Как увеличить размер кнопок "Поделиться", используя сервис [Яндекс/Поделиться](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

UPD. Спасибо [EatMyDust](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212004/) за комментарий к ответу. Исследовал вопрос подробнее.

Яндекс предлагает [4 внешних вида](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/) для блока «Поделиться». Четвёртый из них — с кнопками маленького размера, поэтому увеличивать интересно только первые три.

Предлагаю вариант стилей для кнопок со стороной 32 пикселя вместо 24. Базовые значения — в комментариях к каждой строке.

1. `ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__icon` нужно переопределить для всех видов блока.
2. Для блока со счётчиками нужно добавить `.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__counter`.
3. А для блока с меню — `.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__icon_more:before` и `.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__popup_direction_bottom`.

```css
/* 1 */
.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__icon {
    height: 32px !important; /* 24px */
    width:  32px !important; /* 24px */
    background-size: 32px 32px !important; /* 24px 24px */
}

/* 2 */
.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__counter {
    font-size: 14px !important; /* 12px */
    padding: 8px 10px 0 10px !important; /* 5px 8px 0 8px */
}

/* 3 */
.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__icon_more:before {
    line-height: 22px !important; /* 13px */
}
.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__popup_direction_bottom {
    top: 36px !important; /* 28px */
}
```

```html
<h3>только иконки</h3>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir"></div>

<h3>счётчики</h3>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir" data-counter=""></div>

<h3>иконки и меню</h3>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir" data-limit="3"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Вообще может быть и .ya-share2__container_size_s с буквой "s" на конце, смотря что у него в скрипте прописано, и если у него отображаются не все иконки сразу, а иконки и меню, то при открытии меню все уползет.

Comment: @EatMyDust Спасибо за комментарий. Изучил вопрос внимательнее и переписал свой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, если есть необходимость как то визуально изменить блок, наиболее правильным путём будет использование атрибута data-bare, который является признаком того, что загрузка стилей отключена. Если добавить атрибут, соцсети будут отображаться в виде текстового вертикального списка. А дальше на своей стороне можете делать оформление как удобнее. У вас, по факту остаётся минимальная вёрстка и доступ к API блока.

Answer (score 0):

Нет никакой гарантии, что переопределение стилей, предлагаемое @Gleb Kemarsky, не сломается при ближайшем обновлении блока.

Более безопасным вариантом мне видится подход с использованием свойства [`transform`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/). Такой подход не зависит от внутреннего представления блока и, следовательно, менее чувствителен к обновлениям.

```css
.ya-share2__list {
  transform: translate(25%, 25%) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="ya-share2"></div>

<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
```

Для старых IE можно использовать в качестве фоллбэка свойство [`zoom`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/).

Comment: А для блока с меню какое решение предложите? В нынешнем варианте содержимое выпадающего списка увеличивается сильнее, чем основной ряд иконок..

Comment: Железобетонное решение подсказал @Grey Evil